# What belongs under language-agnostic and what belongs on other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think the tag `language-agnostic` belongs on Stack Overflow and that programming problems do encompass non-language specific questions. However, I am aware of other Stack Exchange sites, specifically [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), that seem entirely dedicated to `language-agnostic` (or similar style) questions.

What belongs under `language-agnostic` on SO and what should go to Programmers SE? Are there any 'hard and fast' rules or is this dealt with on a case by case basis? As someone who has used `language-agnostic` in the past and likely will in the future, are there any rules (written or otherwise) that I should consider when deciding where to ask my questions?

Comment: Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**